# Can't Insert Keyframe - Without Changing Transform

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes

I'm unable to add keyframes for an object's transform without changing the transform.

[See video](https://youtu.be/TOBUAseT9U4).

The object does have keyframing, but trying to add keyframes between these results in the "Keying set failed to insert any keyframes" message. However, if I change the transform, I am able to add keyframes.

I don't want to change the transform, I just want to get keyframes for its current location so I can manipulate the other transform keyframes without affecting its position at this frame. Visual Location keyframes also don't work. Keyframing before or after any existing keyframes does work but that's not helpful.

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file (just the tank for example, or at least a part of it)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't share the tank.  However, the issues persists in all projects, even on just the default cube. It's possible I've changed a setting somewhere? Or perhaps this is just how Blender is supposed to work. I'll add a project with a default cube if that's any use.

Comment: yes please share a file with a default cube, creating a keyframe in the 3D view should work

Comment: Added, thanks..

Comment: it works fine on my computer, so I hope someone will be able to explain   :(

Comment: It _sounds_ as if you have a [keying-set](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html) active, either on different properties, or, for example, with 'Only Needed' checked on linear keys, (so, without an xform, the intermediate frame would not be needed). But I cant find one in your example .blend.

Comment: @RobinBetts, I also thought about the keying set, but I can't see that one's active. I tried using a keying-set set for 'Loc Rot Scale', but that didn't change things.

Comment: @moonboots Just to clarify, the issue is my end? You usually should be able to add keyframes for transforms, between other keyframes, without first changing the value.

Comment: I wonder if you found a solution for this as I am going through the same issue. Cause in this case your workaround is to duplicate the keyframes in the Graph Editor.